# Does Cache activity prevent IIS from unloading an ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a scheduled task to a client's ASP.NET app. These posts cover the idea well:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/
- [What is the Best Practice to Kick-off Maintenance Process on ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841/what-is-the-best-practice-to-kick-off-maintenance-process-on-aspnet)
- ["Out of Band" Processing Techiniques for asp.net applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822/out-of-band-processing-techiniques-for-aspnet-applications)

My question has two parts: First, will IIS unload the application if there isn't enough request activity despite the Cache activity? My client doesn't enjoy as much traffic as stackoverflow so they can't rely on user requests to keep the app 'active'. Obviously, I can't schedule tasks in an unloaded app.

Second, if so, is there a way to prevent IIS from unloading the app outside of configuration or external 'stay-alive' requests? My client's host doesn't allow much configuration tweaking and a stay-alive utility introduces the deployment complexity I'm trying to avoid with an ASP.NET Cache solution.

Thanks a bunch.

Edit/Conclusion: TheXenocide's solution is exactly correct given the question. However, I've decided it is a really bad question. The temptation to cut corners is always looming. I've regained my senses and told my client to use a website monitoring tool to keep the site active. In addition, the scheduled task is going in a windows service despite the extra deployment hassle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, outside the range of changing timeout configuration (which I believe to be possible in Web.config, though I don't know what is and isn't allowed on hosting providers, most of which use Medium Trust) I don't believe there is any other method to keep the application from ending beyond web requests. One thing you might try that may be a little more simple than using some keep-alive service on a local machine might be to add some logic to Session_Start/Session_End that ensures there is always at least one session active; you can use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class from within your application to call your own site and it should still start a new session.

Good luck, and let us know what you do :)

UPDATE: these details now very much depend on which version of IIS and which version of .NET you're running in. Newer versions of each have methods of configuring "always running" applications.